# Looking for a good boolean algebra library

Tags: c, boolean, algebra

I'm writing a tool that deals with some boolean algebra. It's basically a tool to create a state machine based on a user-defined file that contains state names, conditions, and transition information. The method by which state transitions occur is to basically look at a boolean logic table. e.g. transition from State1 to State2 if:

```
(A & B) | (C & ~D) | (E)
```

I've got this all implemented, but now I need to add the ability to do some fun stuff like inverting the whole shebang:

```
~((A & B) | (C & ~D) | (E)) = (via DeMorgan) (~A & ~C & ~E) | (~A & D & ~E) | (~B & ~C & ~E) | (~B & D & ~E)
```

The result must be in [Disjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

Basically, I don't want to write this myself and I'm hoping there's a library somewhere that knows how to deal with stuff like this. I've come across SymPy, but I'm not sure if there is a boolean algebra module.

My app is written in C (probably shouldn't be), but anything will help.

Comment: ...Why can't you just invert the result?

Comment: @TomZych - Basically, any operation I perform needs to wind up in the form of (X & Y) | (W & Z) | ...

Comment: @Tom Zych: So in other words, it seems like he's looking for something that will return a displayable expression tree or symbol list or whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than incorporate code, I found a few great applications that are free for any use (via the University of California). A tool called [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com/index.html) has a nice front end to a few other applications: misii and espresso (included in the install), that perform symbolic Boolean algebra.

There isn't a great command line interface, but you can pass files around to do the job. This performs the minimization I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I was also looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this open source project, although its not a library you can just copy the [Boolean Algebra Class](https://github.com/superibk/BloleanAlgebraicSimplifier) to add to your project